# R remove characters in even rows of a specific column

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove the characters in even rows of a specific column.

My dataset looks like this:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 3 |
| apple | (0,1) |
| banana | 6 |
| banana | (-2,6) |
| cherry | 3 |
| cherry | (4,6) |

And this is what I'm expecting:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 3 |
|  | (0,1) |
| banana | 6 |
|  | (-2,6) |
| cherry | 3 |
|  | (4,6) |

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```r
df$name[!c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- ""
```

This will assign empty string to even rows of the `name` column.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to remove all the `name` values which are repeated, you may use `duplicated`.

```
df$name[duplicated(df$name)] <- ''
df

#    name  value
#1  apple      3
#2         (0,1)
#3 banana      6
#4        (-2,6)
#5 cherry      3
#6         (4,6)
```